# How can I build an Offline Reactjs and Nodejs environment for developing apps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, offline

I need to build an offline Node.js and React.js environment for developing web apps. By Offline I mean no access to internet on the machine that I will use to develop apps.
How to make it possible? Is it possible to download the npm packages on a machine that has Internet and copy them to the offline machine. How would it work exactly?

I tried to copy the "create-react-app" package from the internet machine to the offline machine but it does not work there.

Comment: Pls look into how to create progressive web apps (PWAs)

Comment: you can find lackage npm package from the error screen.
And then you look out that package from the internet and copy to the offline computer manually.
I think it could be worked for offline development.
please share your error screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look below description

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: **************************
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: This is `src/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I updated my browser to the latest version and it started working.